# How to integrate pandas script to tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I want to integrate `pandas` script to my GUI app but I got the following error message when I click on button.

```
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 756, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 771, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 827, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 814, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1951, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 10, saw 4
```

Here is my code:

```
def open_data():
    #This import Excel file and reads it
    data= filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (('Excel file', '*.xlsx'), ('all files', '*.*')))
             
    df = pd.read_excel(data)
def select_country():
    selected = df.loc[df['country'] == values]

window = Tk()
#Set title
window.title ('Report Generator')
# Set window size
window.geometry("800x500")
#Create a button
Button(window, text = 'Import data', command = open_data, bg = 'red', fg = 'white', 
       height = 2, font = 'none 14 bold') .grid(sticky = E, padx = 6, pady = 8 )
country_selected = Label(window, text = 'Select Country')
country_list = Combobox(window, values = ['Russian Federation', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Germany', 
                                          'Italy', 'United States', 'Ukraine', 'Sweden', 'Norway', 
                                          'Netherlands', 'Canada', 'Chile', 'Denmark', 'Brazil', 
                                          'United Kingdom', 'Finland', 'France', 'Greece', 'Israel', 
                                          'Hungary', 'Portugal', 'Mexico', 'Estonia', 'Peru', 'Slovakia', 
                                          'Slovenia', 'Turkey', 'South Africa', 'Switzerland', 'Austria', 
                                          'Spain', 'Poland', 'Czech Republic', 'Morocco', 'Belgium', 'Romania', 
                                          'Latvia', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Lithuania'] )
Button(window, text = 'Generate Report', command = select_country, bg = 'red', fg = 'white', 
       height = 2, font = 'none 14 bold') .grid(sticky = E, padx = 6, pady = 8 )
window.mainloop()
```

I want the **Import data** button to import excel file, the **Combo box** to select the country, **Generate report** button to filter out selected country, and download automatically.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana I have updated with error traceback